# Change marker color in matplotlib legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The code for this example is mostly taken from [Split marker and line in Legend - Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34552273/split-marker-and-line-in-legend-matplotlib) - except, I've added interaction for legend toggling, from https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/event_handling/legend_picking.html

This is how the behavior looks like:

[image: Figure_1]

Let's ignore, for the time being, the logic in toggling the actual plot lines.

What my problem is here, is that when I click on the entries in the legend that are markers only - they do NOT change alpha, nor color for that matter - even if I used `set_markerfacecolor()` specifically to force their color.

On the other hand, when I click on the entries in the legend that are lines only, then they do change alpha, without a problem.

So, how can I get the markers on the legend to also change alpha (or color), when clicked/picked/toggled?

The printouts I get in terminal for the first few clicks on the animated gif are:

```
$ python3 /tmp/test3.py
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1)
(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1)
(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1)
(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1)
(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
...
```

The code is:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import colors

def function_to_split(hand,labl,dividor):

    Hand_L=[]
    Hand_M=[]
    Labl_L=[]
    Labl_M=[]

    for h,l in zip(hand,labl):
        co=h.get_color()
        ls=h.get_linestyle()
        lw=h.get_linewidth()
        mk=h.get_marker()
        mew=h.get_markeredgewidth()
        ms=h.get_markersize()

        LABS=l.split(dividor)

        if len(LABS) != 2:
            print('Split Legends Error: Only exactly 1 Dividor is accepted.')
            print('                     Currently ' + str(len(LABS)-1) + ' dividors were given')
            return hand,labl

        #Line and Color
        LICO = plt.Line2D((0,1),(0,0), color=co, marker='', linestyle=ls,linewidth=lw)
        #Marker
        MARK = plt.Line2D((0,1),(0,0), color='k', marker=mk, markeredgewidth=mew, markersize=ms, linestyle='')

        if LABS[0] not in Labl_L:
            Hand_L.append(LICO)
            Labl_L.append(LABS[0])

        if LABS[1] not in Labl_M:
            Hand_M.append(MARK)
            Labl_M.append(LABS[1])

    return Hand_L+Hand_M,Labl_L+Labl_M



pi=3.14
xx=np.linspace(0,2*pi,100)


fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)

phases=[0,pi/4,pi/2]
markers=['s','o','^']

lines = []
for phase,mk in zip(phases,markers):
    labeltext='Sine' + '*' + str(phase)
    F=[np.sin(x+phase) for x in xx]
    line, = ax.plot(xx,F,color='b',marker=mk,label=labeltext)
    lines.append(line)

    labeltext='Cosine' + '*' + str(phase)
    F=[np.cos(x+phase) for x in xx]
    line, = ax.plot(xx,F,color='g',marker=mk,label=labeltext)
    lines.append(line)

hand, labl = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
hand, labl = function_to_split(hand,labl,'*')
leg = ax.legend(hand,labl)
#plt.savefig('Figure.png')

# https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/event_handling/legend_picking.html
lined = dict()

for legline, origline in zip(leg.get_lines(), lines):
    legline.set_picker(5)  # 5 pts tolerance
    lined[legline] = origline

# NOTE: in the legend, can just click on line to trigger onpick()
# however, clicking on standalone marker in legend won't trigger,
# so you have to click in the whitespace around the legend marker to trigger onpick()!
def onpick(event):
    # on the pick event, find the orig line corresponding to the
    # legend proxy line, and toggle the visibility
    legline = event.artist
    origline = lined[legline]
    vis = not origline.get_visible()
    origline.set_visible(vis)
    # Change the alpha on the line in the legend so we can see what lines
    # have been toggled
    # NB: .set_alpha() works only on lines, not on markers!
    mfcol = colors.to_rgba(legline.get_markerfacecolor())
    print(mfcol)
    if vis:
        legline.set_markerfacecolor( (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0) )
        legline.set_alpha(1.0)
    else:
        legline.set_markerfacecolor( (0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2) )
        legline.set_alpha(0.2)
    fig.canvas.draw()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Without looking much in detail here, I suppose [this is](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11357) the issue.